# Which board has the highest max current via 3.3v pin?

Tags: current, board

Is there any arduino board which can deliver 600-800ma via 3.3v pin? Maybe the Arduino due or the nano 33 ble?

Comment: Uno Plus 3.3V 800mA https://www.waveshare.com/product/arduino-2/boards-kits/arduino/uno-plus.htm

Comment: Yes, that's what i am looking for. Unfortunately, the size of the board is not ideal for my application. The nano 33 ble would be great but i can not find any information about the max current of the 3.3v pin.

Comment: why do you mention Due then? it is huge

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mentioned it because it can probably deliver around 800ma. https://www.mouser.de/arduino-due/ But I am still hoping there is a smaller board.

Comment: yes it can. better source of information is the product page at Arduino. https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-due. but like on all 3.3 V boards the MCU is on this regulator too.

Comment: why not just switch the 3.3v input with a mosfet?

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with mosfets. But in this case I need an extra 3.3v power supply, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your USB will output only 500mA or max to max 1A in some cases. Even if your board is rated for higher output you will be restricted by your source. First step is to increase your source. Secondly check which 3.3V regulator is present on which board and check the datasheet of the regulator to get information about it.
Either ways you can externally add a high current 3.3V regulator and connect it to your 3.3V pin on the arduino. As voltages are equal no current will flow between them.
But remember your source needs to output the higher current first